# Anomalous Antlr4 parsing

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I am working on parsing a grammar using Antlr4 and running into a problem that I cannot understand. In a nutshell, the problem is that Antlr4 parser fails to fully parse a test string in my original grammar but when I add a superfluous rule , the parse is completed. I am providing a simplified version of my grammar to illustrate the issue.

```
grammar my; 
st: 'H' hd | EOF ;
hd: 'D' d | 'C' c | st ;
d: hd ;
c: 'D' c | hd ;
s1: 'D' s1 | c ;
// p: hd ;
SKP: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
```

When provided with the input string:
H C D C C D
Antlr4 parser reports the error:
line 2:0 no viable alternative at input 'DCCD'
and the command *grun st -gui* shows the partial parse tree:

[image]

However, if the commented out rule (p: hd) is included in the grammar, Antlr4 parses the string completely and produces the following parse tree:
[image]

Note that the nonterminal p is not in the original grammar and cannot be reached from the start symbol st. As such, the added production is superfluous and should not affect the parsing of the grammar.

Comment: This doesn't explain the difference the `p` rule introduces in your results, so I won't post it as an answer.  I will point out that it's VERY unusual to make `EOF` an alternative on a rule.  Typically, a start rule should be something like `rule: sr1 sr2 EOF;;` (or something of the like, where the main point is to say that the start rule should consume all input up to and including the `EOF` (this also precludes referencing the start rule in other rules).  It is really too difficult to suggest an alternative as your grammar is so obfuscated as to prevent any interpretation.

Comment: The simple fact that an unreferenced rule impacts the results is probably indicative of some bug in ANTLR, but if it's only triggered by using `EOF` as a rule alternative I'm not sure how seriously it will be considered.

Comment: Thank you very much for quickly narrowing down the problem to the presence of EOF as a rule alternative. However, when I put it at the end of the first rule or remove it, then both the alternatives lead to the same incomplete parse. So, the issue becomes: why is Antlr4 parser not able to find the correct parse for a simple regular grammar?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the proper parse tree for this input should be?  Based on what I saw, your input didn’t actually match the rules.  (Except if we allowed `EOF` as an alternative on `hd` (albeit indirectly through the alternative on `st`)

Comment: (1) Note, the grammar doesn't parse: missing semicolon after the rule `SKP: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip`. (2) Generating a parser for C# the grammar fails to parse the input, but with production `p` uncommented, succeeds. So, it's not limited to Java. (3) EOF should not appear in alts. Use a proper EOF-terminated start rule by replacing the original `st` rule with `file_: st EOF; st: 'H' hd | ;`. With the change, the commented or uncommented rule `p` has no effect either way. (4) This is a bug. It should be reported in https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Comment: @kaby76: Thanks for resolving my question. Sorry, the missing semicolon was simply my copying error.

Comment: @Indie1 This is a great test because it shows a bug in Antlr. Make sure to post it there. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeCargal I am relatively new to Antlr so thanks for pointing out my incorrect use of EOF in the grammar. Once this error is corrected, the results are no longer inconsistent and point to the need to add a null alternative to ```st``` for a correct parse.

Comment: @kaby76 Thanks for suggesting to report the issue as an Antlr bug. I decided against it based on Mike Cargal's response.

Comment: I added the issue.  https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/3851 It must be investigated, because there is a bug here. I will figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to imply that the ANTLR team would ignore the big (not my intention).  It is a bit bizarre, but hopefully is constrained to some side effect of this anomalous use of EOF as a rule alternative.