# ANTLR4 grammar rule that cannot be reached from start rule affects language

Tags: antlr, antlr4

The following minimal grammar shows the issue:

```
grammar test;

call : exp LP exp RP ;

exp : exp LP exp RP | ID;

ID : [a-z] ;
LP : '(' ;
RP : ')' ;
Newline : '\r\n' | '\n' ;
```

If I use `call` as the start rule, then the generated parser will gladly parse the following input:

```
f(x)
```

(tried it in [ANTLR lab](http://lab.antlr.org/), which probably uses the java target, and locally using a C++ target with ANTLR 4.9.3).

If I now add the following rule to the grammar, but keep `call` as the start rule, then the same input does not match `call` anymore.

```
callWithNewline : call Newline;
```

[image: unexpected error]

Why does `callWithNewline` affect whether `call` matches?

If I change the input to have a newline character after it will suddenly match `call` in ANTLR lab (even though the newline is not part of the match of course), but not in the C++ target, so the targets have slightly different behavior here.

I ran into this behavior while unit testing subrules, it does appear that parsing a full grammar which contains this kind of subgrammar somewhere lower in the hierarchy does not lead to issues.

**Edit**

The issue still occurs if I remove the ambiguity

```
grammar test;

callWithNewline : call Newline ;

call : exp LP ID RP ;

exp : exp LP ID RP | ID;

ID : [a-z] ;
LP : '(' ;
RP : ')' ;
Newline : '\r\n' | '\n' ;
```

Comment: I've seen this problem before https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/3851. It's bad because it thwarts referential transparency. The code takes the totality of all rules in determining the follow sets. I wouldn't say it's correct. Prior to the analysis, the code should eliminate all unused rules except a start rule--which must have an EOF at the end of the RHS.

Comment: Glad to see that the situation is known. I am not familiar with the ANTLR internals, but as I understand it the rule exp has the follow set {'(', ')'}, and if I add the callWithNewline rule then the rule call also has a non-empty follow set {'\n'}, and there must be a rule with an empty follow set (the start rule?)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73522066/anomalous-antlr4-parsing

Comment: @kaby76 auto removing "unused" rules would be a bad option. I have grammars with rules I use as separate start rules (to parse only a subset of the language).

Comment: @kaby76 -- Add me to list of folks using multiple entry rules.  Handy, for example if you have a UI to you language and want to parse an `exprOnly` rather than a `compilationUnit` for example.